# Nuxt PWA Icon is displaying on the very bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, nuxt-plugin

I'm trying to add PWA icon on my nuxt app but on chrome browser is rendering on the very bottom of the page can someone help me resolve this issue.

I've put the icon.png file inside my static folder with the name of icon.png,

The icon should not show on my page.

Comment: Not sure to understand the issue. The icon is supposed to be on the bottom right.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the code so that others can better assist you with this issue.